# Как переинициализировать переменные в js

Tags: javascript

На сайте я использую кастомизированный скролл-бар, код нашёл в интернете, работает отлично но есть проблема, в процессе работы с сайтом контентная часть (именно к нему привязан скролл) изменяться, то есть добавляется или убирается некоторая разметка, проблема в том что скролл не адаптируется, и остаётся таким каким он заработал в первый раз, я понял что js файл в котором находиться код скролла нужно переподключить чтобы переинициализировать переменные, изменить скрипт я не в силах, как мне переподключить js файл?

Смысла нет но так же прикрепляю код кастомного скролла:

```js
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    function ScrollBox(container, nameEvent) {
        // имя события прокрутки
        this.nameEvent = nameEvent;
        // родительский элемент в котором находится контент и скроллбар
        this.viewport = container.querySelector('.viewport');
        // элемент с контентом
        this.content = this.viewport.querySelector('.content_2');
        // высоты полученных элементов
        this.viewportHeight = this.viewport.offsetHeight;
        this.contentHeight = this.content.scrollHeight;
        // возможная максимальная прокрутка контента
        this.max = this.viewport.clientHeight - this.contentHeight;
        // соотношение между высотами вьюпорта и контента
        this.ratio = this.viewportHeight / this.contentHeight;
        // минимальная высота ползунка скроллбара
        this.scrollerHeightMin = 25;
        // шаг прокручивания контента при наступлении события 'wheel'
        // чем меньше шаг, тем медленнее и плавнее будет прокручиваться контент
        this.step = 20;
        // флаг нажатия на левую кнопку мыши
        this.pressed = false;
    }

    // для сокращения записи, создадим переменную, которая будет ссылаться
    // на прототип 'ScrollBox'
    const fn = ScrollBox.prototype;

    fn.init = function() {
        // если высота контента меньше или равна высоте вьюпорта,
        // выходим из функции
        if (this.viewportHeight >= this.contentHeight) return;
        // формируем полосу прокрутки и полунок
        this.createScrollbar();
        // устанавливаем обработчики событий
        this.registerEventsHandler();
    };

    fn.createScrollbar = function() {
        // создаём новые DOM-элементы DIV из которых будет
        // сформирован скроллбар
        let scrollbar = document.createElement('div'),
            scroller = document.createElement('div');

        // присваиваем созданным элементам соответствующие классы
        scrollbar.className = 'scrollbar';
        scroller.className = 'scroller';

        // вставляем созданные элементы в document
        scrollbar.appendChild(scroller);
        this.viewport.appendChild(scrollbar);

        // получаем DOM-объект ползунка полосы прокрутки, вычисляем и
        // устанавливаем его высоту
        this.scroller = this.viewport.querySelector('.scroller');
        this.scrollerHeight = parseInt(this.ratio * this.viewportHeight);
        this.scrollerHeight = (this.scrollerHeight < this.scrollerHeightMin) ? this.scrollerHeightMin : this.scrollerHeight;
        this.scroller.style.height = this.scrollerHeight + 'px';
        // вычисляем максимально возможное смещение ползунка от верхней границы вьюпорта
        // это смещение зависит от высоты вьюпорта и высоты самого ползунка
        this.scrollerMaxOffset = this.viewportHeight - this.scroller.offsetHeight;
    };

    // регистрация обработчиков событий
    fn.registerEventsHandler = function(e) {
        // вращение колёсика мыши
        if (this.nameEvent === 'wheel') {
            this.viewport.addEventListener('wheel', this.scroll.bind(this));
        } else {
            this.content.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                this.scroller.style.top = (this.content.scrollTop * this.ratio) + 'px';
            });
        }

        // нажатие на левую кнопку мыши
        this.scroller.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
            // координата по оси Y нажатия левой кнопки мыши
            this.start = e.clientY;
            // устанавливаем флаг, информирующий о нажатии левой кнопки мыши
            this.pressed = true;
        });

        // перемещение мыши
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.drop.bind(this));

        // отпускание левой кнопки мыши
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => this.pressed = false);
    };

    fn.scroll = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // направление вращения колёсика мыши
        let dir = -Math.sign(e.deltaY);
        // шаг прокручивания контента, в зависимости от прокручивания
        // колёсика мыши
        let step = (Math.abs(e.deltaY) >= 3) ? this.step * dir : 0;

        // управляем позиционированием контента
        this.content.style.top = (this.content.offsetTop + step) + 'px';
        // ограничиваем прокручивание контента вверх и вниз
        if (this.content.offsetTop > 0) this.content.style.top = '0px';
        if (this.content.offsetTop < this.max) this.content.style.top = this.max + 'px';

        // перемещаем ползунок пропорционально прокручиванию контента
        this.scroller.style.top = (-this.content.offsetTop * this.ratio) + 'px';
    };

    fn.drop = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // если кнопка мыши не нажата, прекращаем работу функции
        if (this.pressed === false) return;

        // величина перемещения мыши
        let shiftScroller = this.start - e.clientY;
        // изменяем положение бегунка на величину перемещения мыши
        this.scroller.style.top = (this.scroller.offsetTop - shiftScroller) + 'px';

        // ограничиваем перемещение ползунка по верхней границе вьюпорта
        if (this.scroller.offsetTop <= 0) this.scroller.style.top = '0px';
        // ограничиваем перемещение ползунка по нижней границе вьюпорта
        // сумма высоты ползунка и его текущего отступа от верхней границы вьюпорта
        let totalHeight = this.scroller.offsetHeight + this.scroller.offsetTop;
        if (totalHeight >= this.viewportHeight) this.scroller.style.top = this.scrollerMaxOffset + 'px';

        // расстояние, на которую должен переместиться контент
        // это расстояние пропорционально смещению ползунка
        let shiftContent = this.scroller.offsetTop / this.ratio;
        // прокручиваем контент по событию 'wheel'
        if (this.nameEvent === 'wheel') {
        // прокручиваем контент на величину пропорциональную перемещению ползунка,
        // она имеет обратный знак, т.к. ползунок и контент прокручиваются
        // в противоположных направлениях
            this.content.style.top = -shiftContent + 'px';
        // прокручиваем контент по событию 'scroll'
        } else {
            this.content.scrollTo(0, shiftContent);
        }
        // устанавливаем координату Y начала движения мыши равной текущей координате Y
        this.start = e.clientY;
    };

    // выбираем все блоки на странице, в которых может понадобиться
    // прокрутка контента
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]');
    // перебираем полученную коллекцию элементов
    for (const container of containers) {
        // имя события, используемого для прокручивания контента
        let nameEvent = container.getAttribute('data-control');
        // с помощью конструктора 'ScrollBox' создаём экземпляр объекта,
        // в котором будем прокручивать контент
        let scrollbox = new ScrollBox(container, nameEvent);
        // создание скроллбара, исходя из полученных в конструкторе высот
        // контента и вьюпорта текущего блока, регистрация обработчиков событий
        scrollbox.init();
    }
})();
```

Comment: Вместо переподключения целого файла пробуйте вынести строчки функции ниже комментария "получаем DOM-объект ползунка полосы прокрутки..." в отдельный метод `fn.__метод__` и просто вызывайте его при изменениях.